# Why can't I access variables within an $.each loop in Chrome's debugger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scope

I would like to examine some properties from `test_data` (the Object passed into `populateChildTable`) within the `$.each` loop using the debugger. I get a `undefined` error when I try to access them with the debugger

```
var populateChildTable = function(test_data) {

    $.each(test_data.children, function(index, el) {

        $('#my_children tbody')[0].appendChild(createChildRow(el)); // breakpoint here

    })

})
```

Chrome Version 48.0.2564.71 beta (64-bit)

Comment: Of course you can use `test_data` inside the loop? Did you try it

Comment: is it children() ? https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: edited post to ask a different question. Silly me, I knew something was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3491) chromium bug.

`test_data` is available in the scope of `$.each` callback and you can verify that by using `console.log(test_data)` instead of `debugger;`. Dev tool optimisation leads to this behaviour and you can read about that in the thread linked above.